# UIAlertController doesn't dismiss when presented from didUpdateLocations CLLocationManagerDelegate method

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

UIViewController doesn't dismiss on the press of OK tap.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: "s", message: "s", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
    }
    alertViewController.addAction(okAction)
    ROUTEVIEWINSTANCE.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When location changes based on some criteria, I have to show alert. It shows but unable to dismiss. When I tap OK, it throws below error on console.

> unexpected nil window in __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue, _windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIWindow: 0x7ff54ac10d80; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x608000030ce0>>

Comment: Make sure your create and show the alert controller on the main queue.

Comment: I tried to create it on main queue. But still it doesn't dismisses.

Comment: Is your routeviewinstance visible upon presentation?